# Find the second moment of X about x = 0

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, moments

I'm studying moment generating functions. I know that generally to calculate the nth moment of X we take the nth derivative of the moment generating function, and we set t = 0, but I have some troubles to understand what they mean by "about x = 0", or "about the point x = 2". I encountered it also in another exercise and I don't really know, in a practical way, what I have to do with this information after I found, in this case, the second derivative of M. I don't want any solutions but only someone who permits me to understand how to complete this kind of exercises.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Use the Binomial Theorem and linearity of expectation to expand the moment about any value $\nu$ in terms of the raw moments $\mu_i=E[X^i],$ as in $$E\left[(X-\nu)^n\right]=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}\nu^{n-i}\mu_i$$ for any natural number $n.$

Comment: Another approach is to observe that when the mgf is $\phi(t)=E\left[e^{tX}\right]$ then the mgf of $X-2$ (for instance), which gives the moments around $2,$ is $$E\left[e^{t(X-2)}\right]=e^{-2t}E\left[e^{tX}\right]=e^{-2t}\phi(t).$$

Answer (score 1):

In general, the second moment of $X$ about 0 means $\mathbb{E}((X-0)^2),$ i.e. $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$, whereas the second moment about some other value, such as 2, means $\mathbb{E}((X-2)^2)$.

Comment: okay I understood, but if I don't have the Probability density function but only the moment generating function, i have to take the second derivative, but then? Instead of substitute t with 0 I put 2? Because I tried in this way but it didn't work..

Comment: You're right, you can't change what you plug in. But if you expand, e.g., $\mathbb{E}((X-2)^2) = \mathbb{E}(X^2 - 2X + 4)$, now this is all in terms of moments about zero. You can just find the second moment about 0 and the first moment about 0, and then use linearity of expectation.

Comment: Thank you! It has been very helpful